# How to maintain class styling when placed in a table?

Tags: html, css

How can I keep maintain the following "MyDiv" styling when placed into a table?  The font type changes and size when it (div class="MyDiv") is in a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="MyDiv">Text Here</div></td>   <!-- Loses own defined style when place in a table -->
    ...more cols..
   </tr>
</table>

table {font-family: Calibri;...}
.MyDiv, MyDiv {font-family: Verdana;...}
```

Sorry, I'll submit to ridicule as I'm not HTML savvy.  Thx

Comment: Can you provide some code maybe?

Comment: @Logan Serman: Sorry about that.  Code posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first if you're using divs, you don't need to use a table. you could style a div to act just like a table, plus it's more lightweight on the browser.  just add styling to the table, either inlined or in the css and the divs within the table should inherit the parent styles.

```
<table class="MyDiv">
```

or

```
<table style="CSS_DEFINITION">
```

if this still gives you trouble within your css, perhaps you have other styles defined, i'd say use an explicit definition like:

```
.MyDiv.div { DEFINITION }
```

i hope this helps